# find $\lim _{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \sqrt{(x^{2}+y^{2 }-1)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have trouble finding a real solution.
What I get when I tried to change the form to polar form or just directly substitute the value is $\sqrt {-1}=i.$
Can anyone help me? Or the answer is just really $i$.

Comment: Typically "multivariable calculus" means that only real-valued functions are considered.  If you want to allow complex-valued functions, then you have to decide what value the square root of a negative number will take.  This is a question best left to a course in complex variables, I think.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Check what happens for $x=0$ and $y\to 0.$ Then check what happens if $y=1$ and $x\to 0.$